# OpenVAS error 'Failed to find port_list ‘33d0cd82-57c6-11e1-8ed1-406186ea4fc5’

Tags: kali-linux

Operating System: Kali Linux version 2022.1
GSA Version: 21.4.3

I am very new to using OpenVAS and I am currently running into this issue where I try to initiate a quick scan and OpenVAS displays the error shown in the title. I have installed SCAP, CERT and GVMD_DATA using the code

```
sudo runuser -u _gvm –- greenbone-nvt-sync" "sudo runuser -u _gvm –- greenbone-feed-sync --type SCAP" "sudo runuser -u _gvm –- greenbone-feed-sync --type CERT" runuser -u _gvm –- greenbone-feed-sync --type GVMD_DATA
```

However after updating this I still get the same error. Can anyone let me know if I have configured something incorrectly and if so how do I resolve this issue.

Comment: and have you looked up the error? https://www.google.com/search?q=openvas+failed+to+find+port_list

Comment: I have searched up the error and it said to use the code I attached. However I am still receiving the same error whenever I try to initiate a scan

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, also running it under Kali Linux, but I found a post in the Greenbone Forum which guided me to do the following:

Execute the following commands to create the folders:

```
/var/lib/gvm/data-objects/gvmd/20.08/configs

/var/lib/gvm/data-objects/gvmd/20.08/port_lists

/var/lib/gvm/data-objects/gvmd/20.08/report_formats
```

Note: 20.08 is the Greenbone version that I'm running. It may be different to you.

Later, execute the following commands to update Greenbone feeds:

```
runuser -u _gvm -- greenbone-nvt-sync

runuser -u _gvm -- greenbone-feed-sync --type SCAP

runuser -u _gvm -- greenbone-feed-sync --type CERT

runuser -u _gvm -- greenbone-feed-sync --type GVMD_DATA
```

Hope it helps and solve your or anyone issue!